# Panel data: predictor variables with different observation times/frequencies

Tags: time-series, panel-data, autocorrelation, assumptions, robust-standard-error

I would like to estimate a standard logit (panel data):

$\text{logit}(P(y_{i,t}=1))= \alpha + \beta_1 x^1_{i,t} + \beta_2 x^2_{i,t} +\epsilon_{i,t}$.

The problem I am facing, however, is that $x^2$ is *yearly*, whereas $y$ and $x^1$ are *monthly*. Aggregating $x^1$ to the yearly level is not an option. So I naively created 12 observations for each $x^2$ in order to make it monthly and be able to match it to every $y$ and $x^1$. Yet I realize that this might cause problems:

1. It may create serial correlation
2. It artificially inflates the number of observations and hence reduces the SE of $x^2$'s coefficient.
3. The SE of other coefs are not affected.
4. All coefficients remain unbiased.

My **first question** is: is this *diagnosis* of the potential problems correct? Are there other problems I did not think about?

My **second question** is whether a solution to the problems outlined above is to use robust standard errors, clustering the observations by year.